# The lifecycle of Activity and Service

Tags: android

I want to make an application which once is launched and do not present the mainacitivity(the UI I mean) instead launching a Service.The question is if the activity remote the function finish(), will the Service be stopped?

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //where lauching the service
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.finish()` will only close the activity. the service will continue running.

Comment: Thanks.But what is the state of activity which remotes the .finish()? Stop or Destroy?

Comment: onStop(); method is called when you finish() Activity.

Answer (score 3):

Launch the service first and the finish() will only finish the actual activity

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest initialise your service on the onStart and do whatever cleanup code you need to, on your stop.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the **Service** before you `.finish()` the **Activity**